# Add Case Statement in Where Clause

Tags: sql, select, switch-statement, case

I need to add a `case` statement in a `where` clause.  I want it to run either statement below depending on the value of TermDate.

```
Select * 
from myTable
where id = 12345
    AND TermDate CASE  
    WHEN NULL THEN
       AND getdate() BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(dd, 30, StartDate)
    ELSE
    AND GETDATE < TermDate
    END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just use an `OR` condition?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  myTable
WHEN  id = 12345
AND   ((TermDate IS NULL AND 
        getdate() BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(dd, 30, StartDate)) OR
       GETDATE() < TermDate)
```

Comment: may be we also need to add "TermDate IS NOT NULL AND " after "OR " operator

Comment: @codechimp `value < null` returns "unknown", which isn't true, so it doesn't doesn't satisfy the condition. Adding `TermDate IS NOT NULL` will not affect the `where` clause's functionality. It may make the query a tad easier to read, but that's a matter of taste mostly.

Answer (score 2):

Since we all posted three exact answers, obviously too much, here a version that uses your `case when` construction.

use this:

```
select * 
from myTable
where id = 12345
AND   case
      when TermDate IS NULL
           AND getdate() BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(dd, 30, StartDate)
      then 1
      when GETDATE < TermDate
      then 1
      else 0
      end
      = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using `ANDs` and `ORs`. Try the following query.

```
Select * 
From myTable
where id = 12345
AND ((TermDate IS NULL 
          AND GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(dd, 30, StartDate)) 
    OR (GETDATE() < TermDate))
```