# Need help on JOIN and Condition

Tags: sql, if-statement, join, case

**Customer table:**

```
customerId  customerName    startTime   projectDateOfCompletion
1            ANZ             2015-12-05       NULL
2            Barklays        2015-11-25     2016-02-10
3            Grindlays       2016-02-06       NULL
```

**Reports table:**

```
customerId  repId   fromDateTime    toDateTim
1           1       2015-12-05      2016-02-05
1           2       2016-02-06         NULL
2           3       2015-11-25      2016-02-10
3           1       2016-02-08         NULL
```

**CustomerSupport table:**

```
repId   customerSupportRep
1       Jim Daniel      
2       Mark Chad       
3       Juan Maximo
```

Not sure how to format the tables in tabular form.  Hope the look like tables.  I'm looking for help with the following query

```
SELECT 
    t.customerName AS 'Customer Name', 
    u.customerSupportRep AS 'Customer   Support Representative', 
    t.startTime AS 'Start Date/Time'
FROM Customer t
    JOIN CustomerSupport u 
        ON u.repId = ( SELECT repId 
                       FROM Reports 
                       WHERE  
                            customerId = t.customerId AND  
                            (CASE 
                                WHEN (@archiveStartTime IS NOT NULL )
                                    then  @archiveStartTime BETWEEN fromDateTime AND toDateTime
                                ELSE toDateTime IS NULL 
                            END)
                    )                        
    WHERE 
        t.projectDateOfCompletion IS NULL OR 
        t.projectDateOfCompletion = '';
```

If `@archiveStartTime` is NULL, I want records with `projectDateOfCompletion` as NULL
If `@archiveStartTime` is not NULL, then I want to list all records where the `@archiveStartTime` lies between `fromDateTime` and `toDateTime` and `projectDateOfCompletion` is NULL.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
`SELECT t.customerName AS 'Customer Name', u.customerSupportRep AS 'Customer   Support Representative', t.startTime AS 'Start Date/Time'
FROM Customer t
    JOIN CustomerSupport u ON u.repId = ( SELECT repId FROM Reports WHERE  customerId = t.customerId AND  
        ((@archiveStartTime IS NOT NULL
          and @archiveStartTime BETWEEN fromDateTime AND toDateTime)
        or (@archiveStartTime IS NULL AND toDateTime IS NULL )
        ) )
    WHERE t.projectDateOfCompletion IS NULL OR t.projectDateOfCompletion = '';`
```

The query is hard to read, so maybe I've put the condition wrong. My idea is: Instead of the case the you did there, use OR like this(if the query is not running adjust it your self instead of the case)

```
AND  
        ((@archiveStartTime IS NOT NULL
          and @archiveStartTime BETWEEN fromDateTime AND toDateTime)
        or (@archiveStartTime IS NULL AND toDateTime IS NULL ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This query by @Mureinik
      SELECT * FROM  myTable
      WHEN  id = 12345 AND   ((TermDate IS NULL AND 
           getdate() BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(dd, 30, StartDate)) OR
          GETDATE() < TermDate)

from [Add Case Statement in Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919089/add-case-statement-in-where-clause)
helped solve this issue.  Thanks @Mureinik